# Unit testing every table and property for exists in Entity Framework 6 CF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We're using Code First in EF6. We have over 70 tables, and every table/column has a mapping associated with it (because we're using a different naming format for our C# relative to our legacy database).

Code First doesn't check the validation of these mappings at compile time by design. So I want to write a unit test which will loop through the tables, and each property and then check that they simply exist (i.e. give me a list of "bads" which I can then fix).

Here's the code I have so far:

```
        Entities entity = new Entities(); 
        entity.Database.Log = msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        List<string> sql = new List<string>();
        List<string> error = new List<string>();

        foreach (var table in ((object)entity).GetType().GetProperties())
        { 

            foreach (var row in table.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                try
                { 
                    var rtn = entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("select {0} from {1}", row.Name, table.Name));
                }
                catch (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException ex)
                { 
                    sql.Add(string.Format("select {0} from {1}", row.Name, table.Name));
                    error.Add(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem with this code, aside from being slow, is that it also doesn't pick up the ToTable() and [Column()] mappings used within EF6 CF. So the SQL queries actually fail even if the table/property does exist.

Ideally I'd like to call the actual EF6 context object for the table (e.g. entities.TableWhatever.First()) but how do you loop through and then call each object in that way without writing it one line at a time (i.e. how do you loop).

So really I have two problems, either I need to retrieve the mappings to write raw SQL or I need to call the actual EF6 object so that it handles sending the mappings for me (all I really want to run is "select * from [table]" for every table in the EF6 context).

Comment: nitpick: It's not a Unit Test if it interacts with the database; it's an Integration test. It shouldn't be run at every build, it should be run on build in a CI server.

Comment: Is your (implicit) question _"How can I read custom attributes using Reflection"_?

Comment: In EF6 the ToTable() mapping style doesn't appear to use custom attributes as far as I can tell. So I'm not sure that would help me.   

My only question is, how do I loop through every table in an EF6 CF context and pull down a First() of the data within. How I accomplish that is academic, but I'd happily pull in the mappings and write raw SQL, I'd also happily call the DBSet object within the DBContext, but at the moment I cannot figure out how to accomplish either.